# Relationship between Ito Integral and Stratonovich Integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose that $b, \sigma \in L^{\infty}(F)$ and $X_t:=\int_{0}^{t}b_sds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_sdB_s$. For $\pi:0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T$.

Denote $S_M(\pi):=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac{X_{t_i}+X_{t_{i+1}}}{2})B_{t_i,t_{i+1}}$.

Show that $S_M(\pi)\rightarrow\int_{0}^{t}X_tdB_t+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_td_t$ in $L^2$, as $|\pi|\rightarrow 0$.

My idea: we know that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_{t_i}B_{t_i,t_{i+1}}\rightarrow \int_{0}^{t}X_tdB_t$ in $L^2$. So it suffices to show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac{X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}}{2})B_{t_i,t_{i+1}}$$

converges to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_td_t$ in $L^2$.

To do so, we need to simplify the expression

$$\mathbb{E}[||\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac{X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}}{2})B_{t_i,t_{i+1}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_td_t||^2]$$

Where I got stuck.

Comment: Apparently, "Itô vs. Stratonovich" has a rather long history : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263988676_ITO_VERSUS_STRATONOVICH_30_YEARS_LATER